# Should Tapasya be done only in Himalayas ? Which place it should be done?

Tags: tapasya

Is Tapasya to be done only in Himalayas ? Is there any such scriptural injunction ?

Comment: it depends upon the guru's instruction and stage of tapasya. There is no 1 rule.

Comment: when yaksha asks - 'what is tapasaya', yudhishtir responds - 'doing one's oradained duty'.

Answer (score 1):

*Why Himalayas? and in which place should tapasya be done*

Bhagavad Gita 13.11 , may contain the answer.

Sri Krishna ,enumerates in 13th chapter ,  those 20 qualities of mind , which are termed as *jnana* or knowledge,  as it prepares the mind , befitting an aspirant to know the Kshetrajna.(*20 qualities starts from amanitvam , adhambhitvam (13.7).... till Tattva jnarta darshanam*).

Amongst them,

1. **vivikta-deśha-sevitvam** -  Inclination for secluded places ( Here , as per Sri Shankaras Commentary, secluded places need not be say , like dilapidated houses or dirty places , as shuchi or cleanliness is also one amongst 20).
2. **aratir jana-sansadi** - Averting materialistic society (As it would be detrimental to indulge in tapasya living amongst people with materialistic goals . It is better for a tapasvi to avert those whose goals are artha kama only .As per commentary , it does not mean avoiding satsang , or a place where there is a unity of purpose)

In order to resort to a quiet place for contemplation or atma vichara, without affecting the sensitivity / or sentiments of common people (which is clean as well), as per scripturural injunction mentioned above ,Himalayas could be the place of choice for a tapasvi

*PS:Such places are also thronged by people , being popular tourist destinations in these  modern times of Kali Yuga*